# Why does GHC think that the type variable is ambiguous for a class with a default implementation?

Tags: haskell

In the following example I would expect GHC to be able to constrain the variable `a` to type `A` because that's what I say in `instance EAmbiguous A`. However when loading this into ghci I get:

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘Main.$dmcount’

The code in question:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Generics (Rep, Generic)
import GHC.Base (Type)

class EAmbiguous a where
  count :: Int
  default count :: (Generic a, GenericAmbiguous (Rep a)) => Int
  count = genericCount @(Rep a)

class GenericAmbiguous (a :: Type -> Type) where
  genericCount :: Int

instance GenericAmbiguous (f p) where
  genericCount = 10

data A = A deriving Generic

-- The error happens when defining a body-less instance:
--     • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘Main.$dmcount’
--      prevents the constraint ‘(Generic a0)’ from being solved.
instance EAmbiguous A
```

I've been looking at this for a good while and I'm convinced that this should work, but I'm clearly missing something. So my question is: Why can't GHC solve `a` to `A`?

Comment: I suspect `-XDefaultSignatures` and `-XTypeApplications` just don't really work together yet. Both of these are pretty new and not completely mature. The type `count :: EAmbiguous a => Int` was in fact completely useless prior to `-XTypeApplications`, so `-XDefaultSignatures` was probably implemented with the assumption that such a type doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a GHC bug which is fixed in GHC 8.0.2: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12220